How to calculate the total number of different frequencies that are present in audio signal spectrum?
How to calculate the total number of different frequencies that are present in audio signal spectrum? Is that possible?  Linux platform.

Sure, using Fast Fourier Transform, which converts time-domain signal into the frequency space. Consider using e.g. np.fft.fftfreq. Share the code if you have further problems.

Frequency is a continuum so the number of frequencies between any pair of F to  F+f with finite f is always infinite. The human ear is limited in what differences it can distinguish so if you ask how many distinct frequencies can a human ear distinguish in the audio band it would be somewhere between 24 and 40 per octave (factor of two in frequency). See quarter tones. Various programs exist to plot amplitude - frequency waterfall plots as a function of time .

What exactly do you mean, and how do you intend to use it? In a non-trivial audio signal, all frequencies are present (to a certain degree)

Simple, there is an audio file. For the sake of experiment, we limit the frequency range in which we will count frequencies: from 20Hz to 20KHz. Additionally, we can limit this range to only those frequencies that the human ear can distinguish. Now the math - we have to calculate the total number of different frequencies in this range. How can we calculate the total number of frequencies that are present in this range?
